# Geometry Finding measure of a segment using the segments given.

Tags: geometry

So the question is: Suppose A, B, C, D, and E are points in a certain absolute geometry with AB = BC = 7, BD = BE = 3,CD = 8, A − B − C, and D − B − E. Prove AE = 8.

The book I am using is David C. Kay's College Geometry A discovery Approach.

1)I used the definition of betweenness in a metric space to solve this problem. Betweenness A-B-C of points states "We say B is between A and C if AB+BC=AC."

Which approach do you think would be in the right direction?

2. Do you think I can use SSS Theorem to help prove the measure of the segment AE? Or can I not use this because we do not know if the points make a triangle.

Comment: The only way three points would no make a triangle is if they lie on a single line! These points can't lie on a single line because, if they did, we could not have BD= BE.  Since DB= AB and BD= BE, it immediately follows that AE= CD.  It is not a matter of "SSS", it is "SAS" and "vertical triangles.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I see.